# user authentication with powershell

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, powershell, batch

I have the following simple script which I'm using to push some files to a number of Win7 and Server2008 machines. In most cases the local user has no password. However the scripts fails because I'm trying to write through the admin share (c$). What is the most simple way to pass a user for each host machine in the ip.txt?

Also if I'm on a domain how simple is it to modify the script to authenticate with a user and password.

```
 Write-Host 'Deploy Tools'

    $reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("c:\scripts\ip.txt")
    try {
        for(;;) {
            $line = $reader.ReadLine()
            if ($line -eq $null) { break }  
                echo "**** files being copied to: $line ****"
                xcopy c:\scripts\tools  \\$line\c$\windows\system32\ /Y
        }
    }
    finally {
        $reader.Close()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already calling a non-PowerShell command (`xcopy`), you could as well call another one:

```
net use \\$server\c$ /user:$username $password
xcopy c:\scripts\tools  \\$server\c$\windows\system32\ /Y
```

As for storing usernames and passwords in your input file, you can do that quite easily by using the CSV format and the `Import-Csv` cmdlet.

Also, see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/connecting-to-a-network-folder-with-username-password-in-powershell).